# Faster solution than adding multiple "explode" functions within an foreach

Tags: php

Is there an easier and faster solution than multiple explodes to get the results I am looking for. Or do I have to do an `explode` and `foreach` loop.

I started with $values = explode('&', $names);

And this would give me the following results `Array ( [0] => Jane Do [1] => John Jack Do );`

I would like to cycle through those results to look for last names, full names and middle and last names.

`foreach ($values AS $value) {
    $names = explode(' ', $value);
}`

I have different datasets. Here are a few examples:

Value: 
Jane Do & John Jack Do

End Results: 
1. Do
2. Jane Do
3. John Do
4. Jack Do
5. John Jack Do

Value: 
Julie Does & Johnnie Did

End Results: 
1. Does
2. Did
3. Julie Does
4. Johnnie Did

Value: 
Joanne Didnot & Jerry Jason Jean Done

End Results: 
1. Didnot
2. Done
3. Joanne Didnot
4. Jerry Done
5. Jason Done

Do I have to create a foreach loop as above to get my results? Than do a foreach again, and again? Or is there another solution that would be faster and more beneficial?

*Note: If names do go beyond 3 (first middle last), I would like to end the cycle.*

Comment: Nested loops is the way to do it.

Comment: Then keep doing what I doing is that best option. Thanks

Comment: it is big o of n so you can reduce l which a constant not worth trying

Comment: Mohd > you suggesting another way of going about this. I like streamline. I did write the scripting as above and got my results. If it can be done faster ... that is what I am interested in learning.